# Running ffmpeg.exe through windows service fails to complete while dealing with large files

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services, ffmpeg, video-processing

I am using **ffmpeg.exe to convert video files to flv format**. For that purpose i use a **windows service to run the conversion process in background**. While trying to **convert large files**(i experienced it when the file size is >14MB) through **windows service it gets stuck at the line which starts the process**(ie, `process.start();`).

But when i tried to execute ffmpeg.exe directly from command prompt it worked with out any problems.

My **code** in **windows service** is as **follows:**

```
private Thread WorkerThread; 
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{ 

   WorkerThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(StartHandlingVideo));
   WorkerThread.Start();
}

protected override void OnStop()
{ 
   WorkerThread.Abort();
}

private void StartHandlingVideo()
{   
   FilArgs = string.Format("-i {0} -ar 22050 -qscale 1 {1}", InputFile, OutputFile);
   Process proc;
   proc = new Process();

   try
   {

     proc.StartInfo.FileName = spath + "\\ffmpeg\\ffmpeg.exe";
     proc.StartInfo.Arguments = FilArgs;
     proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
     proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
     proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
     proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;

     eventLog1.WriteEntry("Going to start process of convertion");

     proc.Start();

     string StdOutVideo = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
     string StdErrVideo = proc.StandardError.ReadToEnd();

     eventLog1.WriteEntry("Convertion Successful");
     eventLog1.WriteEntry(StdErrVideo);               
 }
 catch (Exception ex)
 {
     eventLog1.WriteEntry("Convertion Failed");
     eventLog1.WriteEntry(ex.ToString());            
 }
 finally
 {
     proc.WaitForExit();
     proc.Close();
 }
```

How can I get rid of this situation.

Comment: Why in the world would you run video conversion tasks as a Windows service?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems you caught a deadlock because you performed a synchronous read to the end of both redirected streams.

A reference from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standardoutput.aspx):

> There is a similar issue when you read
>   all text from both the standard output
>   and standard error streams. The
>   following C# code, for example,
>   performs a read operation on both
>   streams.

```
 // Do not perform a synchronous read to the end of both
 // redirected streams.
 // string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
 // string error = p.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
 // p.WaitForExit();
 // Use asynchronous read operations on at least one of the streams.
 p.BeginOutputReadLine();
 string error = p.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
 p.WaitForExit();
```

> The code example avoids the deadlock
>   condition by performing asynchronous
>   read operations on the StandardOutput
>   stream. A deadlock condition results
>   if the parent process calls
>   p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd followed by
>   p.StandardError.ReadToEnd and the
>   child process writes enough text to
>   fill its error stream. The parent
>   process would wait indefinitely for
>   the child process to close its
>   StandardOutput stream. The child
>   process would wait indefinitely for
>   the parent to read from the full
>   StandardError stream.
>
> You can use asynchronous read
>   operations to avoid these dependencies
>   and their deadlock potential.
>   Alternately, you can avoid the
>   deadlock condition by creating two
>   threads and reading the output of each
>   stream on a separate thread.

Comment: Thank you... It was the real problem and when i just commented the following lines :                             1)proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;                               2)string StdOutVideo = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();                                  it worked for me. I was little bit confused as the code gets stuck at the proc.start(); and read line was after that. Can you tell me when do the read happen? (Is it happen during proc.start()).        Any way thank you for saving me...