# How to get rid of ffmpeg.exe black terminal in .Net C#?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, ffmpeg

I'm using ffmpeg.exe as a process in C# and encoding some videos with it by parameters to that process and it shows black terminal of encoding process like cmd while encoding. I want to get rid of that terminal. I just want processing to be done at back end and no terminal should be displayed while encoding.

Comment: you could use a windows service to run the ffmpeg.exe like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4265286/running-ffmpeg-exe-through-windows-service-fails-to-complete-while-dealing-with?rq=1

Comment: Set `ProcessStartInfoStyle.WindowStyle` to `ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden`, perhaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use ffmpeg to do video encoding in one of my apps. I had exatly the same demands - process in the background, no console windows.
Here is how I invoke my process:

```
Process ffmpeg = new Process();
        ffmpeg.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        ffmpeg.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        ffmpeg.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\...\ffmpeg-3.2-win32-static\bin\ffmpeg.exe";
        ffmpeg.StartInfo.Arguments = "...";
        ffmpeg.Start();
```

Hope this helps!

*Setting UseShellExecute to false allows you to redirect output of ffmpeg into your application and catch printed errors for example.